# JFace MessageDialog is not showing the body(dialog area) by default

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am creating a JFace `MessageDialog`

```
MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(null, "Title", null,
                                "Body message", SWT.YES | SWT.NO, new String[] { Messages.yes, Messages.no }, 0);
```

On one Windows 7 machine when this dialog is opened, it doesn't show its body/dialog area until user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and only title bar is displayed without body. Moreover its position is left bottom corner of the screen. While on pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it opens the dialog in a proper manner and user can see the "Body message" and Yes No buttons on it.

Is it related to some windows or java setting on that machine?

Comment: The position is probably because you have not specified a parent shell. You normally use the current shell as the parent to `MessageDialog`.

Comment: Yeah it looks like but the problem is that its happening only on one machine and that's why I can't reproduce or debug it. May be I need to change this code and give the new jar to test on that particular machine. Thanks.